# Solution for storing custom files by clients in the cloud

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, cloud

1. We have multiple clients using our service.
2. Each client may create multiple projects.
3. Each client may upload multiple files to any of his projects.
4. Each file may have custom meta data associated.
5. Each client may "share" any of the projects to another client.
6. Each client may comment any of his or shared projects/files.

My question is about file storing in a cloud. What will best solution? I thought about Amazon S3 but maybe there are better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore Box.com solution. They are an advanced file management solution in the cloud and support fine-grained permission management as you explained above. Dropbox for Teams is also another option - The permission model is not as extensive as Box, but the sync client is very stable here. In one of my recent projects, I used box.com mainly due to their fine-grained permission controls

You can also build this on S3 (Dropbox and I guess Box too is behind the scenes built on S3). To achieve all the functionality as you mentioned, it is quite some programming work !

Comment: And if I would use S3 what do you think about creating unique bucket per each user or should I rather keep all files in one single bucket and keep information about owner in DB?

Comment: It is better to store in a single bucket. The bucket names has to be unique across entire AWS. There are ways to partition the bucket based on your end user's id (say facebook id). This is all detailed here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313. Take a look !